# hii, In sql query error is coming in update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, correlated-subquery

this is the query
I want to update all values of column in challan table i.e msstype in single query

```
   UPDATE [ProductionDB].[dbo].[Challan]
   SET [MssType] = (select MSSType from TestTable1)
   where ReferenceNo IN (select ReferenceNo  from TestTable);
```

this error is coming

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: as the error states, you are getting multiple values from the subquery `[MssType] = (select MSSType from TestTable1)`. either use `TOP 1` or  convert it into a correlated query based on what you want

Comment: yah multilpe values but no. of msstype and refrence no is same

Comment: I want to update multiple values of that column according to their refrence no

Comment: If you're running a query directly in production without being 100% sure what's going on, at least wrap it in a transaction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
 UPDATE [ProductionDB].[dbo].[Challan]
 SET [MssType] = (select t.MSSType from TestTable1 t 
                  WHERE t.ReferenceNo  = Challan.ReferenceNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
   UPDATE C
   SET [MssType] = T.MSSType
   FROM [ProductionDB].[dbo].[Challan] C
   INNER JOIN TestTable1 T
    ON C.ReferenceNo = T.ReferenceNo;
```

If you can add some sample data of what you are looking at, it can help you get quick and more accurate answers

Answer (score 0):

As said, the error comes due to multiple rows from the subqueries. Try with a loop giving values. Possibly that might correct your problem